# Link modern std libraries to gcc or clang

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, clang++

my gcc version is the following:

```
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

while clang

```
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

but the following code doesn't compile:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main(){
  std::vector<std::jthread> myJThreads; 
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried these so far:

```
g++ -O2 -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic  -lm -lstdc++ example.cpp -pthread -o example
clang -O2 -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic  -lm -lstdc++ example.cpp -pthread -o example
clang++-12 -O2 -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic  -lm -lstdc++ example.cpp -pthread -o example
```

getting:

```
error: ‘jthread’ is not a member of ‘std’;
error: no member named 'jthread' in namespace 'std'
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Update your compiler? (gcc 10, clang not yet, seems).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: @PaulSanders it's the standard library that needs updating not the compiler. Updating the version of gcc may update libstdc++ but it depends on how it's installed. Clang should be able to use the updated libstdc++ version, it's libc++ that doesn't support it

Comment: @AlanBirtles OK.  Pretty ancient, libc++, isn't it?  Certainly is on macOS.

Comment: @PaulSanders no, it's not, it does seem to be lagging behind on c++20 though

Comment: On your Ubuntu release there is a GCC 10 package with its libstdc++ version, so install it with `sudo apt-get install gcc-10` and then use that GCC version instead. GCC 10's libstdc++ supports `jthread`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles OK, thanks.  I got it round the wrong way actually.  Apple have dropped support for `libstdc++` in the last few years, and in older versions of their build tools (which I have to use to support older Macs) it's way behind.  These days, `libc++` is all you get, and that works on (IIRC) Mavericks and later only.  (Typical Apple, pulling the rug out from under people.)